# VBA user form with text box named as Reg.1 for date but when I send to data sheet, it is not a date value. If press F2 in change to date value

Tags: excel

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click()

'dimention the variable
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim addme As Range

'set the variable
Set ws = Sheet3

'error handler
On Error Resume Next


'set variable for the destination
Set addme = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Mandatory fields to be filled
If Me.Reg3 = "" Or Me.Reg4 = "" Or Me.Reg5 = "" Or Me.Reg6 = "" _
Or Me.reg7 = "" Or Me.Reg8 = "" Or Me.Reg9 = "" Or Me.Reg10 = "" Or Me.regCVSource = "" Then

MsgBox "Insufficient data, fill up mandatory fields with (*)asterisk"

Exit Sub

End If

'send the values to the database
With ws

'add the Entry Date (Reg1)
addme.Offset(0, -2).Value = Me.Reg1
```

Comment: Only when press F2 Enter-data converts to date value - wish to make it automatic date value when sent to data sheet

Answer (score 0):

Use `CDate` to convert it to a true date value using your regional settings:

```
addme.Offset(0, -2).Value = CDate(Me.Reg1.Text)
```